# How to make Instagram's Sharing a Sticker Asset example work?

Tags: java, android, facebook, react-native, instagram

I'm trying to follow Facebook's docs for [Sharing a Sticker Asset](http://%20https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/#sharing-a-sticker-asset) on Android without any luck.  Basically when executed the app flickers and then crash.

Could someone look at this code and point out why the app crashes after calling `activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);`? (debugging the code using logcat, I can see the code is definitely executing `startActivityForResult`)

```java
package com.app.my;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

public class InstagramStoriesModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    InstagramStoriesModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
        reactContext = context;
    }

    //Mandatory function getName that specifies the module name
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "InstagramStories";
    }

    //Custom function that we are going to export to JS
    @ReactMethod
    public void share(ReadableMap options) {
        String stickerImage = "https://www.example.com/image.jpeg";
        String backgroundColor = "#000000";

        Uri stickerAssetUri = Uri.parse(stickerImage);

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY");

        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        intent.putExtra("interactive_asset_uri", stickerAssetUri);
        intent.putExtra("top_background_color", backgroundColor);
        intent.putExtra("bottom_background_color", backgroundColor);

        Activity activity = reactContext.getCurrentActivity();
        activity.grantUriPermission("com.instagram.android", stickerAssetUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        if (activity.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null) {
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }
}
```